# Plot multiple columns of points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have a data frame structured as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(combo = c("first", "second", "last"),
                   effect.size = cumsum(rnorm(3)),
                   upper.CI = cumsum(rnorm(3, mean = 3, sd=1)),
                   lower.CI = cumsum(rnorm(3, mean = -3, sd=1)))
```

I want to plot each combo with their associated confidence intervals. However, I am not sure how to plot extra points and connect them on the same line. The intended output is something like:
[image]

I am currently here, but can't figure out how to add the CI's:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=effect.size, y=combo))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2)+
theme_classic2()
```

All of the values I am trying to plot are singular numbers that are an output from a test, so I don't have a distribution of numbers to calculate CI's within ggplot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `?geom_pointrange`

Comment: Yeah this ended up working perfectly, thanks so much! Had no idea point_range was a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_pointrange` or `geom_linerange` if you like.

```
ggplot(df, aes(effect.size, y=combo)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin=lower.CI, xmax=upper.CI)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0),linetype="dashed")
```